# Want to clear custom fields of transition screen after submitting the value in jira

Tags: jira, screen, transition, display

Is it possible that custom fields should be clear or display empty in Jira after submitting the value of transition screen. Basically that screen use on loop(means status of origin is also status of destination. It shows popup screen where I use 5 different custom fields i.e.; date picker, weekly activity etc., and I want that when I submit the value of 1st loop then it's value stored and 2nd time that loop run it doesn't show previous value on that popup. But 1st loop value must be stored in history or somewhere. Because that custom fields values are used in next tasks. I already use post function for clear the resolution or update custom fields. But this clear all values. I don't want that. Is it possible without using Jira plugin?

I already tried post function update custom fields value and also use Jira automation. It copy value after that clear screen. But it doesn't work for me. It clear all custom fields value and I lost my data. Now I want that popup screen should be display empty or clear after submitting the values and values are also stored in somewhere without using any plugin in Jira.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another custom field for history named "stored field". And when you submit, you copy the value of the field and save it in the new field "stored field" with post-function. After that, you can clear the field. So the field will be empty and the value submitted will be stored in the new field.